# Send sms with variable using cordova social share plugin

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am using [social share plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) of cordova to share sms to specific number.

```
<a
    class = "lft"
    onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaSMS('My cool message', 7767051447, function(msg) {console.log('ok: ' + msg)}, function(msg) {alert('error: ' + msg)})">
    <img src="sms.png"  alt="info" height="8%" align="middle">
</a>
```

Instead of passing number it should pass a variable `phone_no` which has phone number in it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: As a side note (which may be the solution to your question) you generally shouldn't put JavaScript code in an `onclick`; it tends to end badly if you do it too much. It still works, but it's considered better practice not to. You should extract it to a function, then call that function, then you can use a global variable or something (I don't JavaScript much) to get the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that u should pass variable instead of number. Then u can do this.

```
<script>
var phone_no="7767051447";
function sendN()
 {
 window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaSMS('My cool message', phone_no, function(msg) {console.log('ok: ' + msg)}, function(msg) {alert('error: ' + msg)});

 }
</script>
```

And call sendN() in onclick of that anchor tag.
By the way in your code you should put your number inside quotes. It would work.